# Create a protocol with default implementation that gives name/title/self of Enum as string

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to create a protocol with default implementation that returns enum itself as string. But not able to find the correct syntax.

This is the code I tried so far, but it is not taking default implementation

```
    protocol TestSelf {
        static var desc: String { get set }
    }
    
    extension TestSelf {
        get {
            static var desc: String {
                   String(describing: self)
        }
        set {
            print(\(new value))
        }
    }

    enum Test: TestSelf { }

Access

    print(Test.desc)
```

Asking me to implement the `desc` in the enum saying `'static var' declaration requires an initializer expression or an explicitly stated getter.` I don't want to initialize it again. It should work with Default Implementation.

Ask:
At all places I don't need to write
`String(describing: Test.self)`
instead I can directly use
`Test.desc`

Comment: What's the problem with the code you showed?

Comment: Asking me to implement the `desc` in the enum saying `'static var' declaration requires an initializer expression or an explicitly stated getter`. I don't want to initialize it again. It should work with Default Implementation. @matt

Comment: Say that _in the question_. — By the way you are saying `TestSelf where Self: RawRepresentable` but your enum is _not_ RawRepresentable.

Comment: Plus of course your "access" `Test.desc` does not print or assign anything so even if it ran it would do nothing.

Comment: So how can I resolve it, with default implementation? @matt

Comment: I do not know what "resolve it" means. Your code makes no sense and you have not explained your goal. The phrase "returns enum itself as string" means nothing to me.

Comment: protocol with default implementation, so all enums can just conform to it and have the `description` by default which is nothing but the enum name itself as a string

Comment: But you know the enum's name. And without any cases, you have no instance of your enum to begin with, so there is nothing to describe. The bare enum name does not signify a "thing".  Please show a _real example_ of what you want.

Comment: I can describe enum name itself even if I know so that at all places I don't need to write `String(describing: Test.self)` instead I can directly use `Test.desc`

Comment: And for some enums I do have cases for some I don't have.

Comment: Please don't vitiate my answer by changing your question after I've answered.

Comment: Updated again @matt, it's just that I reach till that case already.  But noted your point! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this (this is playground code):

```
protocol SelfDescriber {
    static var descriptionOfSelf: String {get}
}
extension SelfDescriber {
    static var descriptionOfSelf: String {
        String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}

enum Test: SelfDescriber {}
print(Test.descriptionOfSelf) // "Test"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, my mistake was `Self.self`. Thank you :)

Comment: @Niki So the same as doing `print(Test.self)`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Weird, isn't it? The OP has already said that `String(describing: Test.self)` works. Of course one's response is "so use it and move on". But the question _also_ appears to involve a specific use of the Swift language so I focused on that rather than the question of what purpose this could possibly serve.

Comment: But that won't be a string value. I am passing it further to a function that accepts a string. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @Niki But you didn't say _that_ in your question either. Please think very hard, next time, about the extremely wide gap between what you say in your _comments_ and what you say in your _question_. You did not _at all_ ask the question to which you actually wanted to know the answer. If you had asked the actual question, properly, there would have been no need for all this back-and-forth.

Comment: In my mind, the question was clear the way I describe it, only after you asked did I get to know how unclear the question might be to other people. Otherwise, I am here to ask questions so would want it to be as accurate to get early responses and proper answers. @matt

Comment: "In my mind, the question was clear" And I'm telling you that it wasn't.

Comment: Yes it's quite easy to lose sight of what is being asked in all the comments here. @Niki note that doing `"\(Test.self)"` will create a string

Comment: Noted! I'll make sure to have the question proper next time, Thanks for all the help @matt